# Node: `fast-sort` package - sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const sort = require('fast-sort');

class sorting {
  static async init(input) {
      const sorted = await sort([1,4,5,2,3]).asc();
      console.log(sorted)
      return "hello";
   
  }
}
```

I am using `fast-sort` package to test out sorting. I kept getting `TypeError: sort is not a function` errors. So, I tried the example on the npm package page. I still get the same error. Is there something I can do here? I am kinda lost.

Comment: `import { sort } from 'fast-sort'` as shown in the [first line of code in the repo README](https://github.com/snovakovic/fast-sort).

Comment: dang, I feel so stupid. Struggled for like an hour for this.

Comment: I feel stupid most of the time--welcome to the club :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-sort) show, `sort` is a *property* of the imported object, not the whole import itself. You need:

```
const { sort } = require('fast-sort');
```

Comment: dang, I feel so stupid. Struggled for like an hour for this.